# Shell Scripting print next line

Tags: shell

My script is reading xyz.txt file line by line using while loop and I want to print next line if conditon matches. e.g if [ "$count" -gt "5" ]; then

Kindly advice.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

awk or sed is a better choice awk example:

```
awk 'FNR>5'  inputfile
```

Same thing in shell

```
cnt=0
while read rec
do
   cnt=$(( $cnt + 1))
   [ $cnt -gt 5 ] && echo "$rec"
done < inputfile
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but will the above solution print next line after condition matches ?

Comment: The condition greater than 5 lines read from the file - yes.  That means line #6 will be the first line you see.  And all lines from #6 - end of file will appear.

Comment: Thanks Jim but 5 is just an example as this value is also a varible. Can I do like cnt=0
while read line
do
   if [ $cnt -gt 5 ]; then                                     cnt=$(( $cnt + 1))
echo $line
done < inputfile

Comment: I do not get what you mean? 5 is really a variable like var?  Then [ $cnt -gt $var ] && echo "$rec".  Why would you want to increment the variable  once you got to its value?  That will stop printing. I think you are trying to do something completely different from your example.

Comment: Oh Great Jim it worked .... :) Thanks a lot for prompt response and valuable support.....